# Django model south 0.7.6 migration problems: Any change in a table with another field with percentage in default value

Tags: django, formatting, default, django-south

I Am having problems after adding a field in my datebase model that contains the format of a datefield.

like this:

```
date_format = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='%B %Y')
```

However in the same migration were some booleans with default values. Going deeper in the problem, and many rebuilding of the test database....

The problem is in any migration in the table with the default value with percentgae signs in it. So not the migration with this field in itselve, but any migration to the same table (see my second answer)

adding a field like this:

```
show_category_name  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

with auto schememigration gives a migration file with this line:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db import models


class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding field 'NewsItemCategory.show_category_name'
        db.add_column('iamweb_newsitemcategory', 'show_category_name',
                      self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=True),
                      keep_default=False)
```

Gives this problem:

```
    bin/django migrate iamwebdjango.db.backends DEBUG (0.006) SELECT "south_migrationhistory"."id", "south_migrationhistory"."app_name", "south_migrationhistory"."migration", "south_migrationhistory"."applied" FROM "south_migrationhistory" WHERE "south_migrationhistory"."applied" IS NOT NULL ORDER BY "south_migrationhistory"."applied" ASC; args=()
Running migrations for iamweb:
 - Migrating forwards to 0020_auto__add_field_newsitemcategory_show_category_name__add_field_weblink.
 > iamweb:0020_auto__add_field_newsitemcategory_show_category_name__add_field_weblink
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.277) CREATE TABLE ROLLBACK_TEST (X INT); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.008) INSERT INTO ROLLBACK_TEST (X) VALUES (8); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.001) SELECT COUNT(X) FROM ROLLBACK_TEST; args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.273) DROP TABLE ROLLBACK_TEST; args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.177) CREATE TABLE STDDEV_TEST (X INT); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.000) SELECT STDDEV(*) FROM STDDEV_TEST; args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.160) DROP TABLE STDDEV_TEST; args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.151) CREATE TABLE DDL_TRANSACTION_TEST (X INT); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.000) CREATE TABLE DDL_TRANSACTION_TEST (X INT); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.155) DROP TABLE DDL_TRANSACTION_TEST; args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.000) PRAGMA table_info("iamweb_newsitemcategory"); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.000) PRAGMA index_list("iamweb_newsitemcategory"); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.000) PRAGMA index_info("sqlite_autoindex_iamweb_newsitemcategory_1"); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.000) PRAGMA index_list("iamweb_newsitemcategory"); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.000) PRAGMA index_info("sqlite_autoindex_iamweb_newsitemcategory_1"); args=()
django.db.backends DEBUG (0.000) PRAGMA table_info("iamweb_newsitemcategory"); args=()
south DEBUG execute "CREATE TABLE "_south_new_iamweb_newsitemcategory" ("date_format" varchar(32) DEFAULT '%B %Y', "show_category_name" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, "id" integer PRIMARY KEY, "menu_index" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE, "name" varchar(64) NOT NULL)" with params "[]"
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:
 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: iamweb:0020_auto__add_field_newsitemcategory_show_category_name__add_field_weblink
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/django", line 33, in <module>
    djangorecipe.manage.main('palmrif.developmentsettings')
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/djangorecipe-0.20-py2.7.egg/djangorecipe/manage.py", line 16, in main
    management.execute_manager(mod)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/parts/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/parts/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/parts/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/parts/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 108, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/migration/__init__.py", line 213, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 235, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 310, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 133, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 107, in run
    return self.run_migration(migration)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 81, in run_migration
    migration_function()
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 57, in <lambda>
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/local_checkouts_dev/iamweb/iamweb/migrations/0020_auto__add_field_newsitemcategory_show_category_name__add_field_weblink.py", line 14, in forwards
    keep_default=False)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/db/sqlite3.py", line 31, in add_column
    field.column: self._column_sql_for_create(table_name, name, field, False),
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/db/generic.py", line 44, in _cache_clear
    return func(self, table, *args, **opts)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/db/sqlite3.py", line 103, in _remake_table
    ", ".join(["%s %s" % (self.quote_name(cname), ctype) for cname, ctype in definitions.items()]),
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/db/generic.py", line 273, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/parts/django/django/db/backends/util.py", line 38, in execute
    sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/parts/django/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 505, in last_executed_query
    return smart_unicode(sql) % u_params
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I Am using South 0.7.6. Weird thing is, this version should have fixed this bug, see: [Release notes 0.7.6. bug fix default boolean value in sqlite](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes/0.7.6.html)

Using sqlite3, python 2.7.2, django 1.3.1 (by the way, in production using mySql, but the test database in sqlite is very convenient)

Note the problem is refering to line 14 in the migration file, which is this line:

```
        db.add_column('iamweb_newsitemcategory', 'show_category_name',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=True),
                  keep_default=False)
```

Not enough arguments.... well for starters: I didn't create this line, South did :)

The stacktrace is a bit confusing, because the last line of the debug lines (before the stack trace is:

```
south DEBUG execute "CREATE TABLE "_south_new_iamweb_newsitemcategory" ("date_format" varchar(32) DEFAULT '%B %Y', "show_category_name" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, "id" integer PRIMARY KEY, "menu_index" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE, "name" varchar(64) NOT NULL)" with params "[]"
```

So it might have to do with South still wanting to parse the string because of the '%B %Y' in this execute command....

After 4 days of struggling with this problem (not fulltime of course) I Am starting to doubt the South way.... however, not found any better alternative.

Comment: Can I see the traceback and the failing line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered on the South mailing list. To summarize: The booleans are innocent, the percents are guilty, Sqlite is a toy and as a result its South backend is a little crazy and apparently has a bug. A new, up-coming version of South should avoid storing defaults in the database, which may solve your problem (at least for testing).

Ticket #317 is irrelevant. Ticket #1192, as it stands, should be fixed by code currently in pull request (or you can pick it from my fork, https://bitbucket.org/shaib/south).

Comment: Shai Berger, thank you very much! I removed the default values with percentages, but I Am looking forward to this new south backend release. (I stick to the official releases). For now SQL lite might be a toy, but for development the only offline alternative for django. But thanks for your effort, and I Am glad you fixed this bug. A good beginning of this new year!

Answer (score 0):

Ah the problem was maybe not in the '%B %Y' default value.
(Hence my edit of the question and title)
There seem to be some problem with default boolean values in sqlite. See my edit in the question.
And there boolean values don't support defaults of True and false.
see [South ticket](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/600)

a suggested solution in the migration file is:

```
 if db.backend_name == "sqlite3":
   default = 1
else:
   default = True
db.add_column('node_entry', 'visible', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=default), keep_default=False)
```

But this does not work, and reading further, it should have been resolved in the south version I Am using...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the problem is in the default value '%B %Y'.
The migration of that one went OK, but after this the new migration went wrong.
I found out because I had 3 fields of the boolean I wanted default to be true.
2 of them was in a table with this percentage in another field.
I marked out these 2 of the migrations and the only one left went OK.

the problem is in recreating the table with the precentage sign

see track:

```
   File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/db/sqlite3.py", line 31, in add_column
    field.column: self._column_sql_for_create(table_name, name, field, False),
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/db/generic.py", line 44, in _cache_clear
    return func(self, table, *args, **opts)
  File "/media/storage/django/sites/palmrif/eggs/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/db/sqlite3.py", line 103, in _remake_table
    ", ".join(["%s %s" % (self.quote_name(cname), ctype) for cname, ctype in definitions.items()]),
```

SO I think I will try to reopen the south ticket and refer them to this site.
And change the title of this ticket.

I added a comment to the ticket: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/317